# probability that one of them hit the target

Tags: probability

the probability that A hits the target is 1/3. the probability that B hits the target is 1/5. they both fire at the target. what is the probability that:

1. one of them hits the target
2. both hit the target
3. neither hits the target

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** As mentioned in the comments, it is safe to assume that $A,B$ are independent events, hence $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Then, you want to find

1. $P(A\cup B)$ (check comment below)
2. $P(A\cap B)$
3. $P\left(\left(A\cup B\right)^c\right)$

Comment: For 1. my answer corresponds to *at least* one. If you mean *exactly* one, then you should calculate $$P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)$$

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are not impacted by each others results and are independent, then the following will work.

**One of them hits the target**

1. 1/3+1/5 **Answer:8/15**

**Both hit the target.**

1. 1/3*1/5
   **Answer: 1/15**

**Neither hits the target**

1. 1/15+8/15=9/15 (The solutions from earlier.)
2. 1-9/15= 6/15
   **Answer=2/5**

Comment: Try elaborating your answer with proper formatting than simply giving the answer to the question which lacks context.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks will do when I have some free time.